# syntax error on bash rm -rf !; unexpected token

Tags: bash, rm

This command is working perfectly when you just type it into console and run;

```
rm -rf !(folder1|file_name|log.txt|*.sh|*.conf)
```

However, when I run it from a bash script, it gives me the following error;

```
./test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 1: `rm -rf !(folder1|file_name|log.txt|*.sh|*.conf)'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the extended glob matching syntax. You need to enable it with `shopt -s extglob` before the `rm` command.